# How to open multiple cmd sessions through a python script?

Tags: python

To generate large number of events I have created the following script in python.

```
import os
while True:
 os.system("dir")
```

To get a large number of events, I am running the python file from multiple Dos sessions (minimum 10). But I am opening each Dos session individually and running the python file.
Is there any way I can open multiple sessions from the script itself? And make the value of number of sessions to be opened configurable?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html , https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will run 10 processes ("sessions"), each process will execute function `worker()`:

```
import os
import multiprocessing

NUMBER_OF_SESSIONS = 10

def worker():
    while True:
        os.system("dir")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range( NUMBER_OF_SESSIONS ):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Comment: It is running good. What is the use of the jobs variable? I could run the code even without it. Also how do I know that 10 sessions have opened? I thought the code will actually open 10 different dos windows.

Comment: @user3913049 1. In `jobs` list `Process` objects are stored. Without `jobs`, no access to information about running processes. For example: `jobs[i].pid` returns ID of i-th process. So, it's good practice to keep process objects. 2.After running the script, open the Task Manager(Ctrl+Alt+Del) and click on `Processes` tab. You will see 11 `python.exe` processes - one for main script and 10 for created processes('sessions').

Comment: what if multiple parameters is needed in function workder?